# What is the best way of implementing a break statement on an interpreter?

Tags: interpreter, brainfuck, compiler-construction

I've been developing an interpreter for [Brain](https://github.com/brain-labs) (a Brainfuck-like language) and have some concerns regarding the design of a **break statement**.

Consider the code below in JS:

```
var Stmt = (function() {
  var Stmt = function() {};
    Stmt.prototype = {
      update_expression: function(update) { return false; },
      value: function() { return this; },
      exec: function(delegate) { },
      zerofy: function (tapeObj) {
        if (tapeObj.data[tapeObj.d_ptr] === undefined) {
          tapeObj.data[tapeObj.d_ptr] = 0;
      }
    }
  };

  return Stmt;
})();

var BreakStmt = (function() {
  var BreakStmt = function(){ };
  BreakStmt.prototype = Object.create(Stmt.prototype);
  return BreakStmt;
})();

var LoopStmt = (function() {
  var LoopStmt = function(stmts, type) {
    this.type = 'undefined';
    this.stmts = null;

    if (tokens[type] === 'TT_BEGIN_WHILE'
      || tokens[type] === 'TT_BEGIN_FOR') {
      this.type = type;
      this.stmts = stmts;
    }
  };

  LoopStmt.prototype = Object.create(Stmt.prototype);
  return LoopStmt;
})();

var IfStmt = (function() {
  var IfStmt = function(stmts_then) {
    this.stmts_then = stmts_then;
    this.stmts_else = null;
  };

  IfStmt.prototype = Object.create(Stmt.prototype);
  IfStmt.prototype.set_else = function(stmts_else) {
      this.stmts_else = stmts_else;
  };

  return IfStmt;
})();
```

The parser will go through the statements recursively and then return an AST. Now imagine an AST with the following statements:

```
LoopStmt
  IfStmt
    IfStmt
      BreakStmt
...
```

The elements `exec` function goes also recursively. In spite of having lots of ideas for this implementation, after a lot of research, I still can't figure out the best way of how to stop this recursivity recursively (if that makes sense) until I find the nearest LoopStmt.

What is the best design for that?
Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research, I believe I found the answer.

Implementing the approach of [tree accumulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_accumulation) would be one the best ideas for my design. In fact, for that, we would only use the approach of **upward accumulation**, where every node (in this case my *Stmts*) has information about its decendents.

In this case, for the mentioned AST:

```
1. LoopStmt 
2.  IfStmt
3.    IfStmt
4.      BreakStmt
   ...
```

Everything we would need to do is to store (or accumulate) the information of the `#4 Stmt` into the `#3 Stmt`, the information of the `#3` into the `#2`, and finally `#2` into `#1`. We would then recursively break the execution of statements up to the nearest loop.

I hope I will help anyone!